# TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined

Tags: angularjs-directive, ionic-framework

This error is while doing ionic push notification program ,here "on "is used to receive notification  but because of following error i cant proceed

```
C:\Users\orcilia49\Desktop\AWpush_v1.1>ionic push --google-api-key AIzaSyCftJZvkhujq8IK4ayTbW9Me-Q9qb78n-c
C:\Users\orcilia49\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\lib\ionic\push.js:140
      response.on("data", function(data) {
              ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\orcilia49\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\lib\ionic\push.js:140:15)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:306:9)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at connectErrorNT (net.js:1015:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)

C:\Users\orcilia49\Desktop\AWpush_v1.1>
```

event.js

```
    angular.module('starter', ['ionic']).run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  var push = new Ionic.Push({
    "debug": true
  });
  push.register(function(token) {
    console.log("My Device token:", token.token);
    push.saveToken(token);
  });
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})
```

Comment: show your event.js file so that can help you

Comment: This error is often the result of testing push registration using ionic serve or a device emulator. In these cases, Cordova will not initialize the push notification service. For this reason, push notifications must be tested on a physical device.

Comment: angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  var push = new Ionic.Push({
      "debug": true
    });
 push.register(function(token) {
      console.log("My Device token:",token.token);
      push.saveToken(token);  
    });
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
 cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }if(window.StatusBar) { StatusBar.styleDefault();}});})

Comment: What Push Lib are you using? You maybe should place that configuration code somewhere inside `$ionicPlatform.ready` function.

Comment: @Rigel, I am also getting same error while executing ionic push command.
Can you please help me if you get some workaround.

Comment: https://github.com/Mahesh/ionic_push